# How to update sqlmap in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sql

How to update `sqlmap` in Ubuntu 12.04.

It's giving me problem. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have get the sqlmap from the repository use the following to update.

```
$ python sqlmap.py --update
```

Comment: Thankyou bro it worked now i have tried the same before but i think i have forget to put -- .